# Finding string and saving its value in string

Tags: php, string, find, save

I want to find the info about things in eBay by URL.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
<?php
$web = file_get_contents('http://www.ebay.com/itm/7-inch-Android-4-2-A13-Capacitive-Touch-Screen-WiFi-Tablet-PC-Front-Camera-8GB/361031774590');
$title = preg_replace('~(.*)<span class="g-hdn">(.*)</span>~','',$web);
$title = preg_replace('~</h1><h2 id="subTitle" class="it-sttl">(.*)~','',$title);
echo $title;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? We tend to say here that 'not working' is the least helpful fault report possible! `;-)` Thus, if you can say what you expected, and what you got in detail, that will make this answerable.

Comment: You'll probably need to process this HTML via DOMDocument - processing HTML using regular expressions is usually more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: (Whilst I am not always sympathetic to eBay as a firm, it's worth knowing that they have in the past taken legal action against scrapers. So it may not be wise to predicate your business success on this project, if it is a commercial enterprise!).

Comment: and what is the $price variable you echo? its never declared anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could also use (as halfer suggested) `DOMDocument` with xpath to get them, and its easier to use their `id`'s instead. Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/7-inch-Android-4-2-A13-Capacitive-Touch-Screen-WiFi-Tablet-PC-Front-Camera-8GB/361031774590';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$title = $xpath->query('//h1[@id="itemTitle"]')->item(0)->lastChild->nodeValue;
$description = $xpath->query('//h2[@id="subTitle"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $title . '<br/>';
echo $description;
```

Comment: thank you for help, it works fine :) but i cannot +1 you because i need reputation for it :(

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be to extract the item number from the URL, then make an API call to eBay to retrieve item information. (The eBay API is free to sign up, and you can start using it immediately.)

A quick and easy way to extract the item# from the URL is to pull out the first 10-13 digit number. There'll be some rare edge cases where this won't work (like a long part number in the item title), but I wouldn't worry about that.

And instead of the API, you can also consider using eBay's RSS feeds to retrieve the data you want.